# How destroy image cloudinary swift 3 version

Tags: swift, image, sdk, cdn, cloudinary

I cant remove images from cloudinary using the iOS sdk, it keeps asking me to provide a signature:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.cloudinary.error Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={message=Missing required parameter - signature})
```

To remove the image from cloudinary I'm using:

```
let config = CLDConfiguration(cloudName: self.cloudname, apiKey: self.apiKey)
let cloudinary = CLDCloudinary(configuration: config)
print(self.separateIdFromUrl(url: (photo?.url)!))
_ = cloudinary.createManagementApi().destroy(self.separateIdFromUrl(url: (photo?.url)!))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem, I was managing the urls with a webserver in nodejs. There's a bug with the cloudinary ios sdk according to @ChrisPrince.
However you can use the admin api inside the server to make it work:

```
cloudinary.v2.api.delete_resources([idCloud], function(error, result){console.log(result);});
```

if you're having this problem just configure cloudinary in you backend and call this to delete the photos.

Comment: Can you give me a reference to this: `they inform clearly that the iOS sdk isn't the ideal tool to remove images`. Thanks!

Comment: I think some actions are only allowed if you use the admin API
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api
At least they say you can have full control over the Cloudinay Database here.
So, if you try using this, instead of the iOS SDK you might be able to accomplish what you want to do.
It's been some time since I had this problem, I can't find the page right now.

But here in the iOS documentation, you see nothing about deleting resources:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/ios_integration


What I didn't understand, was the fact that they have a method in the iOS SDK for this.

Comment: Thanks @Leonel Menezes Morato Lima. I've got a support request out to Cloudinary about this. Shall see what they say.

Comment: Thank you too @ChrisPrince, I'm looking forward to it. Please let me know if you discover something! I'll need this again soon.

Comment: Over a support email, Cloudinary has acknowledged a bug that is making it problematic to do an image delete from the iOS SDK at least in the use case I'm attempting. They indicate they are working on a fix. Hopefully more to follow.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution
Just give it your photoUrl
Check [this](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520352-I-have-deleted-an-image-and-though-it-has-been-removed-from-the-media-library-it-is-still-available-via-URL-) too

```
func deletePhoto(url: String) {

    let photoName = "folderName/" + String(describing: url.split(separator: "/").last!.split(separator: ".").first!)

    let config = CLDConfiguration(cloudName: "CloudName", apiKey: "API-KEY", apiSecret: "API-SECRET", secure: true)
    cloudinary = CLDCloudinary(configuration: config)

    cloudinary.createManagementApi().destroy(photoName) { (response, err) in

        print(response?.result)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate additional information, please. Can you give an example `photoName` resulting from this? Also-- the `destroy` method first parameter calls for an objectId-- and you seem to be passing something different. Thanks!